# Filtering Objects in Class based view Django using Query parameters?

Tags: python, django

I am using Class-based Generic views `Listview` for listing all objects.

My views.py:

```
class PostsList(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "index.html"
```

My Urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',PostsList.as_view(), name = "home"),
]
```

This gives me a list of all the posts. Now I want to **filter/sort** posts based on certain fields of `Post` Model, say `price`. Do I need to write this myself? If yes Which method of `PostsLists` class do I override ? `def get`, `def get_context` ?

I see the get method for Listview defined as below. In it can I pass URL query-parameters as `**kwargs` directly or I have to overwrite the below method in my class.

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ....
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can override the get_queryset method:

Keep a mapping of all the parameters that you can get in the url kwargs.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()

    if self.request.GET.get('price'):
        queryset = queryset.filter(price=self.request.GET.get('price'))
    return queryset
```

Comment: It takes only one argument. You can check out the original code for get_queryset here. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py

Comment: yes you are right . I added a request argument , later removed it . now It's working.

Comment: How do I access url query-parameters in backend ? `self.request.GET.get` is one way . Can I use `self.args` or `self.kwargs`

Comment: Depends on your url scheme. Say if your url is like: `posts/<post_value>/`, you can access the post_value in `get_queryset` like `self.kwargs.get('post_value')`. Thus, you can filter your queryset like `queryset = queryset.filter(price=self.kwargs.get('price_value'))`

Answer (score 6):

When using Django's class based views, avoid overriding `get()` or `post()` if possible. These methods do a lot, and if you override them, you may have to duplicate a lot of the built in functionality. There are normally more specific methods that you can override.

In your case, you can filter the queryset dynamically with the `get_queryset` method. You can access GET parameters with `self.request.GET`. For example:

```
class PostsList(ListView):
    model = Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Filter by price if it is provided in GET parameters"""
        queryset = super(PostsList, self).get_queryset()
        if 'price' in self.request.GET:
            queryset = queryset.filter(price=self.request.GET['price'])
        return queryset
```

If your url captures arguments, you can access them with `self.args` (positional) and `self.kwargs` (name based).

See the docs on [dynamic filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering) for more info.

Comment: Also: you can access args and kwargs from URL using `self.args` and `self.kwargs`

Comment: Some error is coming : `get_queryset() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: First it says `request` object is not defined. So I put that as an argument in the `def get_queryset(self, request)` and then a new error is coming : `get_queryset() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: Also I'm logging `logger.debug(self.kwargs), logger.debug(self.args)` and in url im passing query parameters as `?title=1984` they are coming empty in logging.

Comment: It should be `self.request`, not `request`. I've fixed the code above. You should remove `request` from `def get_request(self)`.

Comment: `?title=1984` is a GET parameter, not an argument captured in the url (e.g. `/title/1984/`. Since it's a GET parameter, you access `title` with `self.request.GET['title']` or, if the key might not exist,  `self.request.GET.get('title')`.