# ListView making queryset based on parameter

Tags: django

I've a ListView which is making a list of items, say, products. And i want to conditionally change this queryset by sending a parameter from template. Say i want to filter something on supplier_id or something else like date. Should i create a new view for each situation or extending the base ListView changin only my queryset depending on condition or i should use only one ListView and process each situation depending on passing argument, so

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
...
def get_queryset(self):
        return Supplier.objects.all()

class ProductBySupplierListView(ProductListView):

def get_queryset(self):
        return Supplier.objects.filter(supplier=self.kwargs['sup'])
```

or

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
...
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.kwargs['sup']:
        return Supplier.objects.filter(supplier=sup)
    else:
        return Supplier.objects.all().annotate(prd_cnt=Count('product'))
```

Or there may be some better pattern for handling multiple conditions sorting problems.

I know that i could do everything like it says in [Filtering Objects in Class based view Django using Query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960428) but is that good design or i should prefer something else, like aforementioned extending and overriding queryset method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering Objects in Class based view Django using Query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960428/filtering-objects-in-class-based-view-django-using-query-parameters)

Comment: yes, but i wondering is that's right from design standpoing? Now i'm trying to extend and override queryset method everytime i need it and have separate url mapping for each sorting condition.

Comment: what do you mean by a "separate url mapping"? The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31960938/2532070) here is correct from a design standpoint. So your second way of filtering is correct, unless there is something else not mentioned that would mean that filtering by supplier needs its own subclassed view.

Comment: By "separate url mapping" i mean that i have distinct ulr path in urls.py and distinct associated ListView with it. And my question which one is better - to have one ListView and choose sorting in single queryset method, or having separate ListView for each sorting condition. And i can't definitely say that choosing sorting on passed argument is better.

Comment: Most likely using one ListView is better, but it would be primarily opinion-based and/or specific to your particular implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's difficult to say which one is better but both approaches work. Anyway at the end i finally found a better approach - is to use django-filters, which is done for filtering based on criteria.